# Git Repo Problem

Tags: android, git, milestone

I was trying to build a android release.  I found this code:

```
mkdir cm4mm
cd cm4mm
repo init -u git://github.com/nadlabak/android.git -b gingerbread
repo sync
vendor/cyanogen/get-rommanager
. build/envsetup.sh && brunch umts_sholes
```

I installed Git, but while I tried repo on git bash, it said "Command Not Found".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `repo` first - there are instructions here:

- http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#installing-repo

Comment: repo installed.. it says it requires python.. so python 2.7 installed.. but on running repo command, it says
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Windows/system32/repo" line 91,in <module>
import readline
ImportError : No module name readline

I cant get what went wrong...