# repo: command not found in automated bash script to build cyanogenmod

Tags: android, bash, shell, cyanogenmod, repo

I am running linux mint 17.2, I have `repo` installed and the path to `repo` is added to my `.bashrc`. I have previously initiated my `repo`.

I have followed the instructions on the [Android Source Downloading](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and [How to Build CyanogenMod](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_grouper#Install_the_repo_command) pages.

**The problem is**: I have written a bash script to automate a number of the commands I would like to use to start a build. My script in a simple form is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Android/Cyanogenmod/cm12_1/android/system
source build/envsetup.sh
repo sync --force-sync -j8
exec $SHELL
```

When I run this, it reports:

```
/home/username/Desktop/Cyanogenmod_cm12_1_Grouper_Build : line 4 repo: command not found
```

If I copy and paste each line into a fresh terminal instance (or by just running a script of `#!/bin/bash exec $SHELL` to open a terminal) it works perfectly.

**What I have tried**: I have tried including a `sleep 10` before the `repo sync --force-sync -j8` but that made no difference. I have also tried explicitly initiating the repo and force adding it to my `PATH` for the current terminal session directly before attempting the `repo sync --force-sync -j8`. The code for that test was the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p ~/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin/repo
cd ~/Android/Cyanogenmod/cm12_1/android/system/
source build/envsetup.sh
PATH=~/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin/repo:$PATH
repo sync --force-sync -j8
exec $SHELL
```

The following 2 questions have a similar title, but neither are my question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682083/repo-command-not-found) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701424/git-repo-problem).

Any help or suggestions would be great, thank you!

Comment: Too much noise in this question. Command not found is command not found, easy and simple. Your script can be boiled down to a shebang and a single command `repo`, and you'll still get the exact same error without what's described in this wall of text.

Comment: Your error is in `PATH=~/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin/repo:$PATH`. What you need is `PATH=~/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: Thank you! I had that in my `.bashrc` actually, just didn't try it correctly when I explicitly tried it in the same terminal session. Although, that brings up another question of why didn't it work without that line in the script? 

My `.bashrc` currently has:

`export PATH=${PATH}:~Android/Cyanogenmod/bin` in it?

Comment: Print `$PATH` inside your script to check if you've really got the right path.

Comment: So, if I do this:
`User@User ~ $ $PATH`
I get:
`bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/michael/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin: No such file or directory`

Comment: No, I'm asking you to `echo $PATH` inside your script.

Comment: It is indeed not there...hmmm
I am currently trying to get the path added correctly to my .profile



EDIT: Tonight is just not my night it appears.....Logged out and back in, all is working. I simply added `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin` to the end of my `.profile` (which is where I curled my repo to), logged out/in and it shows up with `echo $PATH`, and my initial code above functions correctly.

Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, there turned out to be 2 problems. The first, was in my attempted solution of manually setting the path in the script as `PATH=~/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin/repo:$PATH` should have been just `PATH=~/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin:$PATH`.

The second, and overall larger problem, was an incorrectly added `PATH` variable (to `repo`) in my `.bashrc`. This was fixed by adding the line `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Cyanogenmod/bin` to the end of my `.profile`, followed by logging out/in.